# How To Update A Model With No Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I can update models with forms in POST no worries, but I have a function which creates a pdf and I need to add the file path to my model but I cant figure out how.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    questionnaire = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs\\questionnaire_pdfs', null=True)
```

views.py

```
def final_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FinalQuestionForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.finalquestion)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            # here i generate pdf containing all answers to questionnaire
            # i then return the file name and need to save it in my users profile/questionnaire field
            pdf_filename = utils.generate_questionnaire_pdf(request)
            [..save the file to questionnaire..]


            return redirect('questionnaire_complete')
[..cont..]
```

```
class FinalQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FinalQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = FinalQuestion
        fields = ['final_question']
```

Thank you.

--edit-- i think my questionnaire field should be a charfield as im just holding the file name. I still dont know how to save it to the model though

Comment: You should hame `/media/` set for the uploads directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add another FileField like "answers" to your model with null=True. When you create the answer PDF, just update your already created instance with this file.

--edit-- You can assign the form.save() to a variable that will have the value of the saved instance. then you can update that instance.

```
u = form.save
pdf_filename = utils.generate_questionnaire_pdf(request)
u.questionnaire = pdf_filename
u.save()
```

Comment: Hi. My problem is that i dont know how to save the data to 'questionnairre' in my Profile model

Comment: I still cant get it to work but thank you very much, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: what are the fields in your FinalQuestionForm and what data is there in your request.user.finalquestion? Can you post that?

Comment: Hi. I added the FinalQuestionForm. The 'questionnaire' pdf is attached to a different model 'Profile'.

Im trying to save the pdf to a completely different model (Profile) thats otherwise not referenced. Maybe thats not possible.

The Profile model also doesnt have a form.py. Its possible im trying to do things you cant do

Comment: Let's give it a last try. Your FinalQuestionForm is not related to profile but your user is. Try it is like this request.user.profile.questionnaire = pdf_filename. Then save your user.

Comment: Thank you. I think thats actually gotten me a bit further. Im returning a 'SimpleDocTemplate' from my function which creates the pdf. Its now giving me an error saying "'SimpleDocTemplate' object has no attribute 'read'"